# WS02 DeviceMGT to Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, wso2

I am trying to customize the WS02 Device management application. Found the application works with WS02 Carbon server.

Is possible to run the device management api war and jaggery application with Tomcat Server? How to migrate?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but it should work for normal webapp but not the jaggery apps. For webapp you need to copy the relevant war file from repository/deployment/server/webapp to tomcat webapp directory and then copy the relevant jar files to tomcat lib directory from repository/components/plugins and repository/components/dropins directories.